# PHP substring matching whole words

Tags: php, regex, strpos

I am trying write a StringMatch function that returns true when words from one string can be found in another string. The exception is that I don't want matches for things like plurals and other suffixes, and I would also like to avoid matching when a word is prefixed.

To explain more visually:

```
apple watch - apple watches (no match)
apple watch - apple watch repairs (match)
apple watch - new apple watch (match)
apple watch - pineapple watch (no match)
```

I would like is this:

```
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "apple watches");       // output 0
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "apple watch repairs"); // output 1
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "new apple watch");     // output 1
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "pineapple watch");     // output 0
```

I have had some basic success with strpos() I cannot figure out how to return "0" when the second string contains suffixes or prefixes as per examples above.

Here is how I'm trying to solve it:

```
function StringMatch($str1,$str2)
{
    if (SomeFunctionOrRegex($str1,$str2) !== false)
    {
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is a graceful regex solution. I have tried strpos() but it is not strict enough for my needs.

Comment: Add word break assertions, `\b`, to each side of `$str1` and use a regex.

Comment: `preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($str1,'/').'\b/i', $str2)`

Comment: `strpos()` didn't work because you were using for the wrong reasons. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this as I said in the comments

```
function StringMatch($str1,$str2)
{
  return preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($str1,'/').'\b/i', $str2);
}

echo StringMatch("apple watch", "apple watches");       // output 0
echo "\n";
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "apple watch repairs"); // output 1
echo "\n";
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "new apple watch");     // output 1
echo "\n";
echo StringMatch("apple watch", "pineapple watch");     // output 0
echo "\n";
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
0
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37f8d1b02f37c569fc9d652dd308b03334f3884e)

Preg Quote in necessary to avoid issues where `$str1` could contain things like `.` which in Regex is any character.

Furthermore you could strip punctuation like this

```
$str1 = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]+/', '', $str1);
```

For example:

```
echo StringMatch("apple watch.", "apple watch repairs"); // output 1
```

Without removing the punctuation, this will return 0.  Rather or not that is important is up to you.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d892941f62649599f840322a4c07000a1eed2140)

**UPDATE**

Match out of order, for example:

```
//words out of order
echo StringMatch("watch apple", "new apple watch");     // output 1
```

The easy way is implode/explode:

```
function StringMatch($str1,$str2)
{
  //use one or the other
  $str1 = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]+/', '', $str1);
  //$str1 = preg_quote($str1,'/');
  $words = explode(' ', $str1);
  preg_match_all('/\b('.implode('|',$words).')\b/i', $str2,     $matches);
  return count($words) == count($matches[0]) ? '1' : '0';
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfb7378902017b86716ab4d2b0daa8c98441370d)

You can also skip the explode/implode and use

```
 $str1 = preg_replace('/\s/', '|', $str1);
```

Which can be combined to the other preg_replace

```
 $str1 = preg_replace(['/[^\w\s]+/','/\s/'], ['','|'], $str1);
```

Or all together

```
function StringMatch($str1,$str2)
{
  $str1 = preg_replace(['/[^\w\s]+/','/\s/'], ['','|'], $str1);
  preg_match_all('/\b('.$str1.')\b/i', $str2, $matches);
  return (substr_count($str1, '|')+1) == count($matches[0]) ? '1' : '0';
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9344cee5bbab053f7467d0826f25a9ce0ce00dac)

But then of course you can't count the words array, but you can count the number of `|` pipes which is 1 less then the number of words (hence the +1).  That is if you care that all the words match.

Comment: You can match them out of order if you use `preg_match_all` and a capture group with `OR` (the pipe) between the words.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, regex is not always the best solution. Regex needs compiling.
- Second of all, you can split the word based on space and now you have an array of individual words. Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and check for each word in the haystack.

**CODE:**

```
<?php

function StringMatch($needle,$haystack){
    $domain_of_words = explode(" ",$haystack);
    $words = explode(" ",$needle);
    foreach($words as $each_word){
        if(!in_array($each_word,$domain_of_words,true)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

echo StringMatch("apple watch","apple watches repairs"),"<br/>";
echo StringMatch("apple watch","apple watch repairs");
```